# Laravel validation not working properly

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I'm trying to validate my form data. I have used following rules:

```
$rules = array(
        'fname'     => 'required|alpha',
        'lname'     => 'required|alpha',
        'address'   => 'required',
        'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',     // required and must be in email format
        'password'  => 'required|min:8',
        'password2' => 'required|same:password',          // requiredand has to match the password field
    );
```

Even when i try with correct email value. It shows 'The email must be a valid email address.' What is the problem here? Also, in fname and lname, when enter alpha character only, it shows error of The lname may only contain letters.

Comment: Make sure you are receiving correct data for the variables. check the value of 'email'

Comment: maharjanmanish9843@gmail.com seems valid!

Comment: Could you update the question with whatever comes in the request you're trying to validate? dd(Request::all());